# Converting vector of floats in CHW format to a cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, mat

I have a `std:vector<float>` storing elements in `CHW` format. Here,
`C=8, H=48, W=48`.

I wish to store this in a `cv::Mat` in HWC format.

I am clueless as to how to do this.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://answers.opencv.org/question/81831/convert-stdvectordouble-to-mat-and-show-the-image/

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest methods is to create single-channel `cv::Mat`s of size 48 x 48, then merge them all together with [`cv::merge`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga61f2f2bde4a0a0154b2333ea504fab1d).

Below is a function that takes in a `std::vector<float>` with the number of rows, columns and channels then creates a final `cv::Mat` that is of size `H x W x C`.  Since your data is in `C x H x W` format, this unfortunately becomes a bit more difficult as the data per channel is not in a contiguous format.  Specifically, if the data was in a typical `H x W x C` format, the way to access the data in a flattened format would be:

```
HWC ---> index = (i*cols + j) + k*rows*cols
```

`(i, j, k)` would be the row, column and channel indices to access the corresponding element in the vector.  Your data is in `C x H x W` format which means to access the data in a flattened format:

```
CHW ---> index = (k*rows + i) + j*channels*rows
```

Therefore, we will iterate over each channel `k`, and grab the row and column location `(i, j)` and temporarily store it into a vector then use this vector and create a single-channel `cv::Mat`.  We'll then stack these `cv::Mat`s at the very end.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

cv::Mat CreateMatFromVector(const std::vector<float>& data, const int rows, const int cols, const int channels)
{
    // Create stacked vector of cv::Mats
    std::vector<cv::Mat> stacked_mats;
    stacked_mats.reserve(channels);  // Reserve space for efficiency

    // Stack the channels
    for (int k = 0; k < channels; ++k) {
        std::vector<float> pixels;
        pixels.reserve(rows * cols);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
                pixels.push_back(data[k * rows + i + j * channels * rows]);
            }
        }
        cv::Mat channel(rows, cols, CV_32FC1, pixels.data());
        stacked_mats.push_back(channel);
    }

    // Stores output matrix
    cv::Mat output;

    // Create the output matrix
    cv::merge(stacked_mats, output);

    return output;
}
```

To use this function:

```
std::vector<float> data = ...; // Data is created here
cv::Mat output = CreateMatFromVector(data, 48, 48, 8);
```